# How to read custom PNG data with ImageJ?

Tags: png, labview, imagej

I'm just starting with ImageJ and I was wondering if anyone knows of a way of reading the custom data that can be stored in a PNG file. The reason for this is that through LabView I'm generating a 16-bit grayscale PNG file, in which each bin represents a certain height from a measurement. I would like to write the min, max, and bin step in terms of height into the custom data "areas" of the PNG file. From what I've seen, LabView's IMAQ vision tools allow to write it, but I need to read it with ImageJ.

Is it even possible? I didn't find any specific macro that seemed useful yet, but my experience with this program is extremely limited. So any help or advice you can give me will be very useful.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

LabVIEW saves the metadata in it's own format, so you can't easily retrieve it using another tool. You could consider calling the IMAQ CVI function and linking that into ImageJ. It's probably simpler to just write that data into a text file or something.

Comment: Ok, good to know that's what LabView does...Using a text file or similar for data storage was in my mind, but I was hoping for something a little bit more elegant than that.